# ruby error - can I convert this block into a single line with {...}?

Tags: ruby

I created the following (this is part of more code but only this line is at issue):

```
if number_to_test % divisor == 0 then number_of_divisors+= 1 end
```

I wanted to shorten it up with

```
if number_to_test % divisor == 0 { number_of_divisors+= 1 }
```

but I get

```
syntax error, unexpected '{', expecting keyword_then or ';' or '\n'
    if number_to_test % divisor == 0 { number_of_divisors+= 1 }
                                      ^
 syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting keyword_end
```

I thought I could change the long form into a {}
Can you tell me the right syntax (if possible) ?
Maybe I'm just thinking of do end blocks rather than if statements?

Comment: If you like method chaining, you can do `number_to_test.modulo(divisor).zero?`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One line `if` statements in Ruby are done "backwards", so to speak:

```
number_of_divisors += 1 if number_to_test % divisor == 0
```

As might be expected, the same works with `unless` as well.

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
number_of_divisors+= 1 if number_to_test % divisor == 0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
number_of_divisors+= 1 if number_to_test % divisor == 0
```

would be better.

Fixed: ruby doesn't have ++.

Comment: Are you sure that runs? Because it's not valid Ruby.

Comment: -1.  Sorry to downvote but I do not think you can do ++ in ruby !

Comment: @AndrewMarshall & junky I missed that, thanks for reminding :)